# Global Variable / Constant in React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

is there a way in React Native that I can define on a global variable all the strings that I will be using like in Android Development there is a String.xml where you can put all of your strings.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

What' I've done is create a globals module...

// File: Globals.js

```
module.exports = {
  STORE_KEY: 'a56z0fzrNpl^2',
  BASE_URL: 'http://someurl.com',
  COLOR: {
    ORANGE: '#C50',
    DARKBLUE: '#0F3274',
    LIGHTBLUE: '#6EA8DA',
    DARKGRAY: '#999',
  },
};
```

Then I just require it at the top...

```
const GLOBAL = require('../Globals');
```

And access them like so...

```
GLOBAL.COLOR.ORANGE
```

## _____________________

## UPDATE on Feb 10, 2018

This seems to be a pretty popular and useful answer, so I thought I should update it with the more current syntax. The above still works in CommonJS module systems, but now days you're just as likely to run into ES6 and `import`modules rather than `require` them.

### ECMAScript Modules (ESM) Syntax

// File: Globals.js

```
export default {
  STORE_KEY: 'a56z0fzrNpl^2',
  BASE_URL: 'http://someurl.com',
  COLOR: {
    ORANGE: '#C50',
    DARKBLUE: '#0F3274',
    LIGHTBLUE: '#6EA8DA',
    DARKGRAY: '#999',
  },
};
```

// to use...

```
import GLOBALS from '../Globals'; // the variable name is arbitrary since it's exported as default
```

// and access them the same way as before

```
GLOBALS.COLOR.ORANGE
```

Comment: You can also freeze your object to make your constants actually constant.
module.exports = Object.freeze({ key1: val1 });

Comment: just an update, you're missing the "var GLOBAL =..." when importing the variable

Comment: I have problem  - variable value always undefined.

Comment: You'll have to show some code @VishalVaghasiya if you want help. Perhaps create a new question on StackOverflow and send me a link. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: That link isn't valid :(

Comment: Using the updated method, you need to access the variables as follows (adding an 'S'): GLOBALS.COLOR.ORANGE

Comment: Good catch @tmarkiewicz. I've updated the answer to reflect your input

Comment: @harshit I generally use this for read only variables, so it wouldn't replace redux as a state management solution

Comment: @ChrisGeirman Sorry! I am kind of new to redux so I misunderstood it. Can you share some redux with react native code with api call?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal sorry, no. I've never had a need for redux in a production app myself. And that wouldn't be appropriate for this thread. But I'm sure there are plenty of RN/Redux threads out there.

Answer (score 45):

`global` in react native is like the window in web development.

```
// declare a global varible
global.primaryColor = '***';

//now you can use this variable anywhere
console.log(primaryColor);
```

Comment: polluting the global name space is generally frowned upon as an anti-pattern

Comment: @ChrisGeirman what is so anti-patternish about this built-in way, comparing to your answer where you are manually repeating that anti-pattern? just curious

Comment: @injecteer 'Polluting' the global scope means that you define too many variables that are globally accessible. From a programming perspective, you make it difficult to debug and maintain code when you use global variables.

Not sure what you meant by "you are manually repeating that anti-pattern". Do you mean because I'm using the variable GLOBALS? If so, I understand how that'd be confusing. But that could literally be any name, such as CONSTANTS. And it's not ever set in the global scope...which is why you need to specifically import it.

Comment: @ChrisGeirman If I want to have like 2 or 3 "globals", is it still "anti-patternish"? creating a "constants.js" file only for them seems rather as an overkill...

Comment: Do what works best for you in your situation, @injecteer. Overkill or not... it's the developer's right to decide

Answer (score 11):

I too made a module like in [Chris Geirman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33504644/4773911), but was not able to reference it with the require. Instead I got it to work with `import * as GLOBAL from '../Globals';`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to switch between languages depening on platform localisation.

**fetch node_module via npm**

```
npm i react-native-localization --save
```

**Define variables in class:**

```
// Localisation.js
let LocalizedStrings = require ('react-native-localization'); 
let strings = new LocalizedStrings ({ 
 en: { 
     loginTitle:  "Login",
 }, 
 de: {
     loginTitle:  "Anmelden",
 }
})
```

**When you need the strings:**

```
var STRINGS = require ('./Localization');
<Text>{STRINGS.loginTitle}</Text>
```

Comment: Thank you! How will the app know if you want to use the en or de since when you call  the strings {STRINGS.loginTitle} no en or de

Comment: The react-native-localization will do the thing. It will check the the device preferences and then pick the needed language automatically.

Comment: Im new to React. I come from the iOS/Android world. Is there a way I can have one dedicated file for localised strings similar to those platforms?