# Set and access mutable app global params with React Navigation in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is there a way I can declare mutable global parameters within React Navigation StackNavigator? I'm trying to achieve a central point of reference for global variables in the app.

Suppose this is my index.android.js :

```
import {
AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import {MainScreen} from './components/mainScreen';
import {SegundoScreen} from './components/segundoScreen';
import {TerceraScreen} from './components/terceraScreen';

const SampleAppStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home :                { screen : MainScreen },
    SegundoScreen :    { screen : SegundoScreen },
    TerceraScreen :        { screen : TerceraScreen }
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none'
  },
  {
    appGlobalVariables: {
      Session : '',
      variable1 : 'cool',
      variable2 : 'coolant',
      variable3 : 'color',
      variable4 : 'none',
      objetoUno : {},
      objetoDos : {},
      objetoTres : {}
    }
  }
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApplication', () => SampleAppStack);
```

Then in directory components/mainScreen.js, I supposedly have...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text,View} from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class MainScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {dummyProp:'dummyProp'};
 }

 render() {
  var {appGlobalVariables} = this.props.StackNavigator;
  return (
   <View>
     <Text>Received from App's global variables: {appGlobalVariables.variable1}</Text>
   </View>
  );
 }
}

export {MainScreen}
```

And in directory components/segundoScreen.js, I supposedly have...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text,View} from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class SegundoScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {dummyProp:'dummyProp'};
 }

 render() {
  var {appGlobalVariables} = this.props.StackNavigator;
  return (
   <View>
     <Text>Received from App's global variables: {appGlobalVariables.variable2}</Text>
   </View>
  );
 }
}

export {SegundoScreen}
```

And in directory components/terceraScreen.js, I supposedly have...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text,View} from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class TerceraScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {dummyProp:'dummyProp'};
 }

 render() {
  var {appGlobalVariables} = this.props.StackNavigator;
  return (
   <View>
     <Text>Received from App's global variables: {appGlobalVariables.variable3}</Text>
   </View>
  );
 }
}

export {TerceraScreen}
```

I've tried it, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use `global` like mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36994650/4805414. Also see accepted answer to the belonging question. Maybe that's an alternative for you, too.

Comment: It worked. Thanks dude. The only part I don't so much like about it is that I constantly have to precede with "global," but I'll take it.